# Socket.io and MongoDB requireing two submisions before registering to DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Me and a friend are developing a backend for a communications application. 
We are using **socket.io** and **MongoDB** with Mongoose. When the submit button on the form is clicked for the first time, my custom "db.js" module returns only an empty array after using the mongoose.find() method. On the second clicking of the submit button, however, the find method finally returns a non-empty array populated with the data just sent over websockets. This is obviously not the expected behavior.

## **Socket IO handler**:

```js
io.on('connection', (client) => {
    console.log('someone connected');
    client.on('create', (data) => {
        data.type = 'rift';
        console.log('--socket.io new data--');
        console.log(data);
        switch (data.type) {
            case 'rift':
                let newRiftObject = {
                    owner: 69420,
                    title: data.title,
                    name: data.title,
                    desc: data.desc,
                    banner: `/img/banner/${data.title}.jpg`,
                    roles: [],
                    locale: "en_US",
                    members: [69420]
                }
                database.riftCrud.create(newRiftObject);
                database.riftCrud.read(data.title);
                break;
            //...
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

## **Schema:**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
module.exports.riftSchema = new Schema({
  owner: Number,
  title: String,
  name: String,
  desc: String,
  banner: String,
  roles: Array,
  locale: String,
  members: Array
});
```

## **form.js**

```js
function submitHandler(event) {
    let formData = $('#form').serializeJSON();
    // event.preventDefault();
    // const socket = io();
    socket.emit('create', formData);
}
```

## **DB communication (separate file):**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dbName = "riftDB";
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/riftDB', { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, (err) => {
    if (!err) { console.log(`connection to mongoDB ${dbName} succeeded`) }
    else { console.log(`Error connecting to mongoDB ${err}`) }
});
var { riftSchema } = require('./rift.model.js');
var Rift = mongoose.model('Rift', riftSchema);
module.exports.riftCrud = {
    create: function (object) {
        Rift.create(object);
    },
    read: function (riftName) {
        Rift.find({ name: riftName }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) { console.log(err) }
            else { console.log(result[0]) }
        });
    }
}
```

## The returned output:

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
listening on 3000
connection to mongoDB riftDB succeeded
someone connected
someone connected
--socket.io new data--
{ title: 'asdf', desc: 'nible', type: 'rift' }
[]
--socket.io new data--
{ title: 'asdf', desc: 'nible', type: 'rift' }
[
  {
    roles: [],
    members: [ 69420 ],
    _id: 5ed9dd9b8579873337e09394,
    owner: 69420,
    title: 'asdf',
    name: 'asdf',
    desc: 'nible',
    banner: '/img/banner/asdf.jpg',
    locale: 'en_US',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    roles: [],
    members: [ 69420 ],
    _id: 5ed9dda28579873337e09395,
    owner: 69420,
    title: 'asdf',
    name: 'asdf',
    desc: 'nible',
    banner: '/img/banner/asdf.jpg',
    locale: 'en_US',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

As you can see, the first submission returns an empty array (each new submission being denoted by a new `--socket.io new data--` header) but the second is a full object (what we want.)

Changing my database interaction code to use `findOne()` instead of `find()` and removing the `[0]` from from the `console.log` statement accordingly since it shouldn't be an array merely returns null.

```
Thank you in advance, 

   Jon K.
```